# Android align layout center

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, centering

I`m trying to make Layout with LOGO and TEXT align center between ActionBar and Bottom layout.
Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B6OA.jpg)

I try to do it, but it does not work corectly. It make the layout with logo by center of the scree. It look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf0Ye.jpg)

Does the anybody know where is misteke?
My code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

//MainLayout
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="text" >

//LOGO Layout
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/mainlogo_height"
    android:src="@drawable/gerb_big" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="#900000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/OA_size" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="text"
    android:textColor="#900000"
    android:textSize="@dimen/NU_size" />

</RelativeLayout>

//Bottom Layout
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal|center" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="home_Click"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/home" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="news_Click"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/database" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/anons"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="annons_Click"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/faculty"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/anons"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:onClick="faculty_Click"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/category" />

</RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a `LinearLayout` that is the child of the root layout and wraps all the other layouts and then change

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:gravity="center" >
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout0"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" >
```

or add `android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout1"` to your LOGO layout

Comment: android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" must be written :
android:gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code and my layout. I hope this is what you need. :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/square_empty" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/square_empty" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

and here is the snapshot :-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:layout_above=@id/relativeLayout1` to your logo layout.